# Como alinear el "spin button" de un select box

Tags: html5, css3

Tengo el siguiente problema en mi interfaz gráfica, tengo un `select box` con unos estilos específicos lo que sucede es que la flecha que enmarca las opciones no se alinea con el tamaño de el `select box` de esta manera:
[image: SelectBox]

Como tal quiero lograr que el `spin button` se ponga al final y no quede como en medio, cabe resaltar que también pasa con los tipo numero y date, agradezco su ayuda.

HTML:

```html
<div class="tipoCedula">                   
                        <select class="question" name="tipoCedula" id="tipoCedula" required autocomple="off">
                            <option value="" selected disabled hidden></option>
                            <option value="1">Cédula De Ciudadania</option>
                            <option value="2">Cédula De Extranjeria</option>
                        </select>
                        <label for="tipoCedula"><span>Tipo De Documento</span></label>
                    </div>
```

CSS

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
 input[type=password]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{ 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}

input[type=number] { -moz-appearance:textfield; }

input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=date]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=select]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{
    margin-right: -300px;
}
input[type=date]:required:invalid::-webkit-datetime-edit {
    color: transparent;
}
input[type=date] { color: transparent !important; } 
.active input[type=date] { color: inherit !important; }

input,
span,
label,
textarea,
select{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
  display: block;
  border: none;
}

textarea:focus,
input:focus,
select:focus {
  outline: 0;
  /*padding: 2px;*/
}
/* Question */

input.question,
textarea.question,
select.question{
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: padding-top 0.2s ease, margin-top 0.2s ease;
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Hack to make "rows" attribute apply in Firefox. */
}

/* Underline and Placeholder */

input.question + label,
textarea.question + label,
select.question + label{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease;
  transition: width 0.4s ease;
  height: 0px;
}

input.question:focus + label,
textarea.question:focus + label,
select.question:focus + label {
  width: 100%;
}

input.question:focus,
input.question:valid {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
select.question:focus,
select.question:valid {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

textarea.question:valid,
textarea.question:focus {
  margin-top: 10px;
}



input.question:focus + label > span,
input.question:valid + label > span {
  top: -50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
}
select.question:focus + label > span,
select.question:valid + label > span {
  top: -50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
}

textarea.question:focus + label > span,
textarea.question:valid + label > span {
  top: -50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
}

input.question:valid + label,
textarea.question:valid + label,
select.question:valid +label{
  border-color: green;
}

input.question:invalid,
textarea.question:invalid,
select.question:invalid{
  box-shadow: none;
}

input.question + label > span,
textarea.question + label > span,
 select.question + label > span{
    display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: #8F8F8F;
  font-size: 100%;
  top: -22px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease, font-size 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
  transition: top 0.2s ease, font-size 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
}
```

Comment: Puedes probar con un "float: right;" en el select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sino prueba de esta manera:

```
<div class="tipoCedula">                   
                <select class="question pull-right" name="tipoCedula" id="tipoCedula" required autocomple="off">
                    <option value="" selected disabled hidden></option>
                    <option value="1">Cédula De Ciudadania</option>
                    <option value="2">Cédula De Extranjeria</option>
                </select>
                <label for="tipoCedula"><span>Tipo De Documento</span></label>
            </div>
```

Comment: Funciona de una manera extraña como tal me lo alinea pero el spin pasa ha estar como debajo del input, sabes que puede ser?

Comment: prueba aplicando las dos clases, pull-left al label y pull-right al select a ver si hace algo

Comment: Perfecto, ahora funciona de manera correcta.

Comment: Genial ! Abrazo

Answer (score 2):

Podrias probar ponerle una clase "pull-left" al label "tipo de documento" o un "pull-right" al select

```
<div class="tipoCedula">                   
                    <select class="question" name="tipoCedula" id="tipoCedula" required autocomple="off">
                        <option value="" selected disabled hidden></option>
                        <option value="1">Cédula De Ciudadania</option>
                        <option value="2">Cédula De Extranjeria</option>
                    </select>
                    <label class="pull-left" for="tipoCedula"><span>Tipo De Documento</span></label>
                </div>
```

Comment: Como tal no genera ningún cambio, muchas gracias de igual manera.

Comment: Esta debería ser una edición de la otra respuesta... o al contrario. Te sugiero hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas de lo que hablo.